Linden Mayer System with multiple symbols
I am trying to use the lindenmayersystems package to draw the following pattern which resembles the cantor set: x, xox, xoxoooxox, ...
I have defined the following system:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cantor}{
        \symbol{X}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
        \symbol{Y}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}
        \rule{X -> XYX}
        \rule{Y -> YYY}
    }%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw lindenmayer system [lindenmayer system={cantor, axiom=X, order=3}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

I would like the x's to render as a filled circle, and the o's the render as an unfilled circle. Unfortunately, I was not able to find any examples quite similar to this. Any help would be appreciated.
Perhaps using a linden mayer system is not the best idea here, and a recursive solution  would be best.

Please add the few missing lines, which will turn your code snippet into sth. that we can copy&compile. Thank you

Right, sorry! I added enough code to make it a working example.

I just get 8 dashes from your MWE.  For those of us who don't know what it is supposed to look like, could you tell us a bit more?

Sure. At order 1, the system produces "X". At order 2, the system produces "XYX", and at order 3 the system produces "XYXYYYXYX". I am hoping that the X's can be rendered as filled circles, and the Y's rendered as open circles. So it should be a sequence of circles, spaced equally, where some are filled and some are not. I had it draw lines to give you the idea of where the filled circles should be. So after each move forward, I want it to render the appropriate object. I'm not entirely sure that this is possible within the lindenmayersystems package.

I should point out that I am not tied to the idea of rendering an object. What I really want is a way to differentiate the two types of positions. So perhaps moving forward, then drawing either a filled or unfilled square would suffice.

My original solution (below) was convoluted by the fact that I felt compelled to recreate the OP's early comment that, At order 1, the system produces "X". At order 2, the system produces "XYX", and at order 3 the system produces "XYXYYYXYX".
However, when it was later discussed that these results could be considered as orders 0, 1, and 2 (rather than 1, 2, and 3), everything fell much more simply into place.  It simply amounts to making the \symbol macros place the desired icon via a \node command, followed by a \pgflsystemmoveforward to advance to the next location.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cantor}{
    \symbol{X}{\node{$\bullet$};\pgflsystemmoveforward}
    \symbol{Y}{\node{$\circ$};\pgflsystemmoveforward}
    \rule{X -> XYX}
    \rule{Y -> YYY}
  }%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw lindenmayer system [lindenmayer system=
      {cantor, axiom=X, order=0}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw lindenmayer system [lindenmayer system=
      {cantor, axiom=X, order=1}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw lindenmayer system [lindenmayer system=
      {cantor, axiom=X, order=2}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}


ORIGINAL ANSWER (ORDERS 1, 2, and 3)
I can't say I know what I am doing here.  But I noticed if I just used simple rules without counters, symbols were being duplicated more than expected.  So I played around.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\newcounter{myindex}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cantor}{
    \symbol{X}{\ifnum\themyindex<2\stepcounter{myindex}\else
      \pgflsystemmoveforward\node{$\bullet$};\setcounter{myindex}{0}\fi}
    \symbol{Y}{\ifnum\themyindex<2\stepcounter{myindex}\else
      \pgflsystemmoveforward\node{$\circ$};\setcounter{myindex}{0}\fi}
    \rule{X -> XYX}
    \rule{Y -> YYY}
  }%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw lindenmayer system [lindenmayer system={cantor, axiom=X, order=1}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw lindenmayer system [lindenmayer system={cantor, axiom=X, order=2}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw lindenmayer system [lindenmayer system={cantor, axiom=X, order=3}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


This is wonderful! Thank you very much. I guess the key takeaway here is that you can render an image whenever a symbol is encountered by adding it to the symbol definition. I couldn't quite follow the counter logic, but I removed it, and it renders perfectly. So for instance, \symbol{X}{\node{$\bullet$};\pgflsystemmoveforward;}. This just drops a bullet whenever it encounters X and then moves forward. Similarly for Y.

@misogrumpy I can see in my early attempts, I was failing to \pgflsystemmoveforward on X, which accounted for added difficulties.  However, when I do as you suggest, I get the proper result, but for the next higher order (order=1 produces an order=2 diagram).

The single bullet is the base case for the construction anyhow, so having it be order=0 is good. Thank you again!

In OpTeX, we can use \replstring:
\def\tmpb{\X}
\def\nextlevel{\replstring\tmpb{\Y}{\Y\Y\Y}\replstring\tmpb{\X}{\X\Y\X}}
\let\X=\bullet \let\Y=\circ
\def\printstring{\centerline{$\tmpb$}}

\printstring
\nextlevel\printstring
\nextlevel\printstring
\nextlevel\printstring

\bye

Note that we needn't TikZ, only very simple macros are used.

Surely using the lindenmayersystems library is attracting. However, the rules are quite easy to be implemented directly.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\cantor}{m}
 {% #1 = number of iterations
  \misogrumpy_cantor:n { #1 }
 }

% choose the symbols for X and Y
\tl_const:Nn \c_misogrumpy_cantor_x_tl { \,\textbullet\, }
\tl_const:Nn \c_misogrumpy_cantor_y_tl { \,\ensuremath{\circ}\, }

% variables
\seq_new:N \l__misogrumpy_cantor_levels_seq % for the final printing
\tl_new:N \l__misogrumpy_cantor_level_tl % current level
\tl_new:N \l__misogrumpy_cantor_temp_tl % for substituting

\cs_new_protected:Nn \misogrumpy_cantor:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__misogrumpy_cantor_level_tl { X } % initialize
  \seq_clear:N \l__misogrumpy_cantor_levels_seq
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1+1 } { \__misogrumpy_cantor_next: }
  \__misogrumpy_cantor_print:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__misogrumpy_cantor_next:
 {
  % store the previous level
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l__misogrumpy_cantor_temp_tl \l__misogrumpy_cantor_level_tl
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__misogrumpy_cantor_temp_tl { X } { \c_misogrumpy_cantor_x_tl }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__misogrumpy_cantor_temp_tl { Y } { \c_misogrumpy_cantor_y_tl }
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l__misogrumpy_cantor_temp_tl { \! }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__misogrumpy_cantor_temp_tl { \! }
  \seq_put_right:NV \l__misogrumpy_cantor_levels_seq \l__misogrumpy_cantor_temp_tl
  % compute the next level
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__misogrumpy_cantor_level_tl { Y } { YYY }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__misogrumpy_cantor_level_tl { X } { XYX }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__misogrumpy_cantor_print:
 {
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l__misogrumpy_cantor_levels_seq { \\[-1ex] }
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Zero}
\cantor{0}

\section{One}
\cantor{1}

\section{Two}
\cantor{2}

\section{Three}
\cantor{3}

\end{document}


